# Setting function type in JSON redis using nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, redis, ioredis

Hi I am trying to store a JSON in redis using ioredis. This JSON comprises of one function too. The structure of my json is something like:

```
var object = {
  site1: {
    active: true,
    config1:{
      // Some config in JSON format
    },
    config2: {
      // Some other config in JSON format
    },
    determineConfig: function(condition){
      if(condition) {
        return 'config1';
      }
      return 'config2';
    }
  }
}
```

I am using IOredis to store this json in redis:

```
redisClient.set(PLUGIN_CONFIG_REDIS_KEY, pluginData.pluginData, function (err, response) {
  if (!err) {
    redisClient.set("somekey", JSON.stringify(object), function (err, response) {
      if (!err) {
        res.json({message: response});
      }
    });
  }
});
```

When I am doing this the `determineConfig` key is truncated from the `object` as `JSON.stringify` removes it if the type is function. Is there some way I can store this function in redis and excute that once I get the data back from redis. I do not want to store the function as a string and then use `eval` or `new Function` to evaluate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is a means to encode arbitrary data objects into strings which can be parsed back into its original object at some later time. As such, JSON only encodes "simple" data types: `null`, `true`, `false`, `Number`, `Array` and `Object`.

JSON does not support any datatype that has a specialized internal representation, such as Date, Stream, or Buffer.

To see this in action, try

```
 typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Date)) // => string
```

Since their underlying binary representation cannot be encoded into a string, JSON does not support encoding of Functions.

```
JSON.stringify({ f: () => {} }) // => {}
```

While you indicated that you did not wish to do so, the only way to accomplish your goal would be to serialize your function into its source code (represented by a string), as in:

```
const determineConfig = function(condition){
  if(condition) {
    return 'config1';
  }
  return 'config2';
}

{
  determineConfig: determineConfig.toString()
}
```

And either `exec` or otherwise re-instantiate the function at the receiving end.

I'd recommend not doing this, since `exec()` is very dangerous, and so has been deprecated.